# Sitefinity injects HTML into head

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

Sitefinity is injecting the robots meta tag into my page. In the razor template there is no allocation in the area for any content variable. The html is simply added before the closing head tag:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex" /> <title>
Test page title
</title><meta name="robots" content="noindex" /><meta name="Generator" content="Sitefinity 10.0.6415.0 OME" />
```

How do I stop this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a similar approach as in this blog post:

https://sitefinitydevelopment.com/blog/how-to-remove-sf_apppath-javascript-variable-from-a-sitefinity-mvc-page.html

Basically, you need to subscribe to IPagePreRenderCompleteEvent and remove the meta tag from the header controls.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'no-follow' is injected into the page then the property **Allow external search engines to index this page and include in Sitemap
Priority in Sitemap** in the Title & Properties.

[image]